# How can I place a <ui:component> within another <ui:component> with primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm struggling with the implementation of `<ui:compontes>`. I was able to let this szenario work:

```
<html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:tabview id="tab">
    <p:tab title="Client">
    <ui:include src="view/clients/clientMasterData.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabview>
```

But if I place the 'clientMasterData.xhtml' in another `ui:component` like this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:component id="clients"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" ... 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h1 align="center">Client Page</h1>

<p:tabView orientation="left">
    <p:tab title="tab 1">
        <ui:include src="view/clients/clientMasterData.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab 2">

    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab 3">

    </p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

I get the error: `<ui:include src="view/clients/clientMasterData.xhtml"> Invalid path : view/clients/clientMasterData.xhtml] with root cause
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException`

But from the example before I know that the path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the mistake. I didn't respect the hierarchy of my xhtml pages.
The solution was to use the relative path. In my example: `clients/clientMasterData.xhtml` because the parent xhtml is located in the `view/` folder.